# No result after registering my password filter in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows, dll, active-directory

I wrote a dll file similar to a **Password filter**, as per the instructions from Microsoft Technet blog and few other sites. I just need to get the clear text password via "**PasswordChangeNotify**" method, in an Active directory environment(I had also included *fprintf*'s to write to a log file, to see what it's doing).

I had specified my dll's name in the regedit [as per this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Now the methods "**InitializeChangeNotify**", "**PasswordChangeNotify**", "**PasswordFilter**" are never called, when a user changes his password. I had even visited [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/336242/registered-password-filter-on-windows-2008-never-fires)
and installed the corresponding MS vcredist-x64! But no use, Am finding it extremely annoying! Somebody help me out please. Or is there any other way to capture passwords in an Active directory environment?

**Note**: If I call "**InitializeChangeNotify**" (as it doesn't need any argument) of my dll file from a normal C# file, its writing to the log (working fine).

Comment: Did you remember to reboot the server after editing the registry?  Are you sure it is a 64-bit DLL?  What language did you write the DLL in?

Comment: Yes @HarryJohnston ! I had rebooted several times but still of no use..

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, you should not write a password filter in any .NET language. They state that "The behavior of any high-level language, framework, or runtime in the components that are loaded by core operating system processes is undefined."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841927